# How to export firebase user account with phone Auth enabled

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to export and import firebase user accounts.

Its works fine for user who has registered with email password auth.

But the export process file doesn't include user phone number, hence the users registered using phone auth are shown as anonymous users when importing.

How to export and import user accounts which support phone auth registration.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The phone number is indeed not yet included in the data that the CLI exports. We want to add it at some point, but as usual: no promises or ballpark timelines.